# AngularJS Component: Passing parameters using = binding

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to pass parameters to an AngularJS Component (Angular 1.5). But, I am not able to access them in the Component. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the code?

http://jsbin.com/fopuxizetu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: It is treating what you pass into `param` and `hero` as variable names. You seem to be expecting them to be treated as values. If you want them to pass in values should use the '@' binding.

Answer (score 7):

In the first snippet, I replaced the binding with `@` so that it takes values. If you use the `=` binding it expects you to pass in variables.

In the second snippet I used the `=` binding but created variables using `ng-int`.

```js
    angular
        .module('client', [])
        .component('testComponent', {
            template: '<h1>{{$ctrl.param}}</h1>',
            controller: function() {
                // this.param = '123';
            },
            bindings: {
                param: '@'
            }
        })
        .component('heroDetail', {
            template: '<span>Name: {{$ctrl.hero}}</span>',
            controller: function() {},
            bindings: {
                hero: '@'
            }
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>AngularJS Example</title>

    <!-- AngularJS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="client">
    Test
    <test-component param = "Test123">  </test-component>
    <hero-detail hero="Superman"></hero-detail>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Snippet using = binding.

```js
    angular
        .module('client', [])
        .component('testComponent', {
            template: '<h1>{{$ctrl.param}}</h1>',
            controller: function() {
                // this.param = '123';
            },
            bindings: {
                param: '='
            }
        })
        .component('heroDetail', {
            template: '<span>Name: {{$ctrl.hero}}</span>',
            controller: function() {},
            bindings: {
                hero: '='
            }
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>AngularJS Example</title>

    <!-- AngularJS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="client" ng-init="testParam= 'Test123'; testHero='Superman'">
    Test
    <test-component param = "testParam">  </test-component>
    <hero-detail hero="testHero"></hero-detail>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```